# Extend code.InteractiveInterpreter with a history, tab completion,

Tags: python, python-3.x, libreadline

Is there an easy way to extend `code.InteractiveInterpreter` with a history, tab completion, ...?

What I'm doing right now is subclassing `code.InteractiveInterpreter` to receive input from and transmit results to a different process. Now I'd like to add features like history (arrow-up and -down) and completion (tab) the same way the normal Python shell / IPython does it.

I can't find much information on this except the Python / CPython / IPython source code and GNU readline:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interactive.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html

Is GNU readline the way to go? How do I use it in Python 3?